# How to tell when a cmd process is done in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to write a launcher for an application in C#, and part of that process is a robocopy operation. The process is *supposed* to tell me when it's done via the Exited event on the process object, but for some reason when the process closes, it doesn't do that. It's happening - I know it's working - but I don't want to have to set a timer here. What am I doing wrong?

```
private bool AllCopyComplete = false; //Property

    public void CopyAll()
        {
            Log.Info("Performing initial copy of files...");
            string robocopyCommandAll = "/c robocopy <SOURCE> <DEST> /E & exit";
            AllCopyProcess = new Process();
            AllCopyProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe", robocopyCommandAll);
            AllCopyProcess.Exited += AllProcessExited;
            AllCopyProcess.Start();
            while (!AllCopyComplete)
            {
                Log.Info("Waiting (initial copy)...");
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
            return;
        }

    private void AllProcessExited(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AllCopyComplete = true;
            Log.Info("All files updated");

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I forgot to use this:

```
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Comment: The answer to the proposed duplicate question covers this as well.